# Dynamics 365 Online Vs On-premise Solutions export

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Is it possible to export a solution from an online organization of Dynamics 365 (V9), and import it in an On-premise organization (V9), to get all customizations and configurations of the online version to the on-premise version ? Is there any limitation or restriction ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most of the Customization such as entities, Fields, Views and so on shall be ok to import On-premise but there can be few of the customization which will not work as On-Line is higher version than On-Prem. I would suggest you go increment i.e small package at first and then keep implementing it.

Refer to these Links for more understanding

1. [Link 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/maintain-managed-solutions)
2. [Link 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/introduction-solutions)
3. [Link 3](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/305989/error-when-importing-solution-to-on-premise/883996)